# NSMutableArray making app crash

Tags: ios, xcode

In my application I have many mutable arrays, that I fill up in a for loop with int i; i = 0; i++; The application worked, but now it started crashing, giving this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x32bb888f 0x34b5d259 0x32b019db 0xb1f07 0x372a160d 0x32b8ca33 0x32b8c699 0x32b8b26f 0x32b0e4a5 0x32b0e36d
>   0x32c5b439 0x350edcd5 0xa8e45 0xa8de0) terminate called throwing an
>   exception(lldb)

The problem is that I don't know which array is causing the problem, and i have more than 12 arrays. so I don't know how to solve it. I tried using the Zombie objects feature, but it doesn't tell me which array is causing trouble.

I also can't understand because in the code I do this first:

```
[messagename removeAllObjects];
[messageframe removeAllObjects];
[messagetext removeAllObjects];
[MapViewArray removeAllObjects];
[DeleteButtonArray removeAllObjects];
[DeleteButtonArray removeAllObjects];
[DeleteButtonArray removeAllObjects];


MapViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
messagename = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
messageframe = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
messagetext = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
DeleteButtonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
messageframe = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and then i only add objects in this way:

```
 [messagename addObject: textname];
```

i don't even access a certain index!!

Comment: You will need to debug it, and also will need to add more info here, so we can help you, but why you remove all objects from DeleteButtonArray 3 times?

Comment: You need to show the code that does `objectAtIndex` on the arrays; not the initialisation of the arrays.  Also you can use a debugger to track down this issue; set a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and take it from there.

Comment: use try-catch. this probably will find the evil.

Comment: Don't use a capital letter as the first letter in an ivar name - DeleteButtonArray and MapViewArray. This is against Apple guidelines for a long list of reasons, and just makes it harder for others reading your code to help you (in the future).

Comment: I used try catch and it was very helpful, at least it prevented the app from crashing..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an index out of an array that doesn't exist. "It is out of bounds [0,0]". Likely to be in the loop where you are inserting items into the array rather than within the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well Said by @Robin van Dijke, You can go to the breakpoint navigator panel in XCode and set an exception breakpoint which will break your program when the exception is about to rise.

Also check the array is nil or not before removing the elements.
ie.

if(messagename != nil){

[messagename removeAllObjects];

}
else
{

messagename = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}